# WKWebView backForwardList getting messed up when going back

Tags: swift, wkwebview

in my webapp I try to establish going back and forth via swipe gestures.

Using WKWebView this should be as simple as

```
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

While navigating through the web content the navigation stack `webView.backForwardList` is filled up as expected.

`URL1 -> URL2 -> URL3 -> URL4` 
leads to
 
`webView.backForwardList.item(at:0) -> URL4`
`webView.backForwardList.item(at:-1) -> URL3`
`webView.backForwardList.item(at:-2) -> URL2`
`webView.backForwardList.item(at:-3) -> URL1`

but as soon as I try to go back in history by either using a swipe gesture or manually triggering `webView.goBack()` the navigation stack gets messed up and enters a loop.
Going back from `URL4` to `URL3` in history leads to `webView.backForwardList.item(at:-1) -> URL4` and not `URL2` as I would expect it.
So whenever I go back the navigation stack gets stuck in a loop between the last two URLs.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: As I just saw, `webView.backForwardList.forwardList` stays empty after `webView.goBack()` is called.

Comment: To set custon Headers, I create a mutable copy of the request in `decidePolicyFor navigationAction`, cancel the current request and start a new one with my custom headers set. Might this have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: Of course it does. If you cancel the current request and start a new one it is treated as a new request not as going back in history.

Comment: did you solve this? I got the same problem as well

Comment: It was due to cancelling the request and generating a new one with custom headers. You should check if you cancel and create a new request in your loading mechanism and think of an alternative.